# Rails - SQLite, table error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite

im new in Rails and i have a project for school.
I did this :

```
bundle exec rails g migration AddTypeToCarte type:belongs_to
```

But i have an error when i did a migration (rake db:migrate)

This is my class AddTypeToCarte

```
class AddTypeToCarte < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_reference :cartes, :type, index: true, foreign_key: true
  end
end
```

My error in my terminal is :

```
SQLite3::SQLException: no such table: cartes: ALTER TABLE "cartes" ADD "type_id" integer/Users/pierresisson/Documents/hearthdex/db/migrate/20150515075035_add_type_to_carte.rb:3:in `change'
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::SQLException: no such table: cartes: ALTER TABLE "cartes" ADD "type_id" integer
/Users/pierresisson/Documents/hearthdex/db/migrate/20150515075035_add_type_to_carte.rb:3:in `change'
SQLite3::SQLException: no such table: cartes
/Users/pierresisson/Documents/hearthdex/db/migrate/20150515075035_add_type_to_carte.rb:3:in `change'
```

I tried to add type_id but it doesnt work.
I think i have no table named "cartes" :/
I need your help please,
Thanks !

Comment: What are you trying to do? Add "belongs_to"? You should write that in your model, not migration. If you are trying to add connect two tables, then you need to add a reference to it in your migration.

Comment: Yep im trying to do this.
Okay thanks.
I try to connect carte and type but it seems i have no table "carte"
i will try to add reference in my migration even if i already have one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First create model named Carte (*rails g model Carte*) then run *rails generate migration AddTypeRefToCarte type:references*.

Also in the Carte model file add *belongs_to :type*.
You can read more about associations [here](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html).